# Unit testing MatSelectChange with if else

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am writing unit tests and I have this simple method that does something depending on the value of matSelectChange.
How can I test this so the code coverage is 100%?

```
 selectionChanged(matSelectChange: MatSelectChange): void {
            if (matSelectChange.value === '1') {
                this.service.doSomething();
            } else if (matSelectChange.value === '2') {
                this.service.doSomethingElse();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi, please check this video from 16:55 :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7dcSpinbgqM - I think you should create two unit tests for each case.

Comment: @MateuszŚcigała thank you I will definitely check it out because unit tests are a hell to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write the test like

```
describe('mat-select behaviour', () => {
  it('sould call doSomething if value is "1"', () => {
     const service = TestBed.inject(ServiceClass)
     spyOn(service, 'doSomething')
     const matSelect = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('mat-select'))
     matSelect.triggerEventHandler('selectionChange', {value: '1'});
     fixture.detectChanges()
     expect(service.doSomething).toHaveBeenCalledWith('1');
  });
 it('sould call doSomething if value is "2"', () => {
     const service = TestBed.inject(ServiceClass)
     spyOn(service, 'doSomethingElse')
     const matSelect = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('mat-select'))
     matSelect.triggerEventHandler('selectionChange', {value: '2'});
     fixture.detectChanges()
     expect(service.doSomethingElse).toHaveBeenCalledWith('2');
  });
})
```

before you can use the service class you must provide it in test setup

```
providers: [
   ServiceClass
]
```

Comment: thank you this worked for me. I only had to change one line
 expect(service.doSomething).toHaveBeenCalled(); and that was it for me.

Comment: glad to help. Pls mark my answer as answer thanks :)